# how to make text that crosses image or div transparent or different color?

Tags: html, css

I was searching dribble website templates and came across this  design and I am wondering is this text over image effect achievable in CSS or not?[image]

Comment: you can use 2 containers and background-clip : example https://codepen.io/gc-nomade/pen/bGBoGgN (not sure duplicate helped for your case )

Answer (score -1):

You cannot make the text change color when it hits the image.

But you can make a `span` with in it 3 more spans with other colors
.

You can also make the text transparent using `color: someTransparentColor;` in  css.

Answer (score -1):

The solution is to use two textes :

- one white inside the div element that contain your image
- one colored outside this element, but under the image

Then you have to find the good way to give them the exact same position.